# Background music continue to playing when open an app or change scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have game made with SpriteKit. When I open the app and I change the scene, while music is playing (for example from Music app on iPhone), the music stops. How can I continue to play music when I open the app and when I change scenes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your app's capabilities, and set the category on the Audio Session.

I think you're looking for:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
```

There are other categories as well, but here are the docs on [AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryplayback).

> When using this category, your app audio continues with the Silent
>   switch set to silent or when the screen locks. (The switch is called
>   the Ring/Silent switch on iPhone.) To continue playing audio when your
>   app transitions to the background (for example, when the screen
>   locks), add the audio value to the UIBackgroundModes key in your
>   information property list file.

Here's a capture of the XCode Capabilities Panel:

[image]

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: Did you add the background mode in XCode?